# In C++ programming, is the main() function static like in java or non-static like in C?

Tags: c++, function, static, c++17, program-entry-point

In C++ programming, is the `main()` function static like in java or non-static like in C?

Comment: In Java, it's a static member function of a class. In C++, it's not a member of any class. C doesn't have member functions at all. The static linkage of C and C++ does not exist in Java. (The "static" keyword has very different meanings in different languages, and several in C++.)

Comment: What difference would it make? You cannot call `main` from another function. You can't get a function pointer to `main`.

Comment: `static` means different things in those languages though. Is the word "sea" a pronoun like in German or a "yes" like in Spanish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.start.main#1

> A program shall contain a global function called `main`, which is the designated start of the program.

It cannot be a `static` function.